# Android remote control for app prototyping

Tags: android, wifi, remote-access

First of all ill include the disclaimer that I honestly hope this is the right place to ask this.

I am in the process of developing an app that essentially turns a phone into an appliance. I know this is fairly common in the android development community. The phone will work as a sensing device, taking pictures and then locally processing them. It will have internet access over celular network but won't have much humman interaction (if at all). I am in the prototyping phase and I was wondering what type of tools can I use to remotely access the phone once I deploy it to the testing site.

I should be able to remotely access the phone anytime to edit app configurations. Hopefully even deploy new versions of the APK if that's a possibility in case any major bugs are found. How is this done?

I've been searching for an answer for a while on google and since I can't find it I suspect I'm not asking the correct question or using the correct terms. I keep finding solutions to remote controling other things using my phone. I want the exact opposite and I want it to be always running so that can launch it anytime. Solutions like TeamViewer and AnyDesk don't work for me because they require human intervention to start the remote control.  and since I can't find it I suspect I'm not asking the correct question or using the correct terms.